# How can I create Wikipedia's footnote highlighting solely with jQuery

Tags: jquery, highlighting

I would like to duplicate Wikipedia's footnote highlighting from in-text citation click solely in jQuery and CSS classes. [I found a webpage that describes how to do so with CSS3](http://www.impressivewebs.com/dynamically-highlight-content-wikipedia-css3/) and then a JavaScript solution for IE. I would like however to do so solely with jQuery as the site I'm doing it on already has a bunch of jQuery elements.

I've come up with a list of the process.

1. In-Text Citation Clicked
2. Replace highlight class with standard footnote class on `<p>` tag of footnotes that are already highlighted.
3. Add highlight to the appropriate footnote
4. Use jQuery to scroll down the page to appropriate footnote.

I've come up with some jQuery so far but I'm extremely new to it relying heavy on tutorials and plugins to this point. Here is what I have with some plain English for the parts I haven't figured out yet.

```
$('.inlineCite').click(function() {
   $('.footnoteHighlight').removeClass('footnoteHighlight').addClass('footnote');
   //add highlight to id of highlightScroll
   //scroll to footnote with matching id
});
```

If I had a method to pass a part of the selector into the function and turn it into a variable I believe I could pull it off. Most likely I'm sure one of you gurus will whip something up that puts anything I think I have done to shame. Any help will be greatly appreciated so thank you in advance.

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I copied Wikipedia's superscript markup verbatim:

```
<sup class="reference" id="cite_ref-1">
    <a href="#cite_note-1">
        <span>[</span>1<span>]</span>
    </a>
</sup>
```

And used the following jQuery:

```
$(".reference > a").click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var $el = $(href);

    $(".ref-highlight").removeClass("ref-highlight");
    $el.addClass("ref-highlight");
});
```

The key is grabbing the `href` off of the link that was clicked, and then using that to select the element and apply the highlight class.

Also, you don't need to scroll the page down programmatically, because the browser handles this for you automatically.

Here's a complete working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/dkWJm/2/

---

**Update:** I noticed in your comment below you'd like to animate the scrolling, here's how you would do that:

```
$(".reference > a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var $el = $(href);

    $(".ref-highlight").removeClass("ref-highlight");
    $el.addClass("ref-highlight");
    $("html, body").animate({"scrollTop": $el.offset().top}, 3000);
});
```

**Notes:**

- We're canceling the default action of the link in this case (using `event.preventDefault()`), which would be to jump to the element with the `id` matching the clicked link's `href`.
- Using [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to smoothly scroll the `html` element down to the appropriate position, which is determined using [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) on the target element.
- The `duration` argument (I specified 3000) is what you would tweak to lengthen/shorten the duration of the scroll.

Here's an example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/dkWJm/4/ **(Updated to work in IE8/Chrome/FF 3)**

Comment: CSS really ought to have a selector for the currently active anchor fragment. This type of functionality shouldn't have to require JS.

Comment: @Lèse: There is a CSS3 selector that does this (http://thinkvitamin.com/design/stay-on-target/), it's just not supported by IE :(

Comment: Ah, I guess I should have read the question better. Well, hopefully IE will eventually support it.

Comment: This looks good, I'll be trying it out tomorrow. The reason I want to use jQuery to slide down is for the animated slide rather than the standard browser behavior.

Comment: I've just began working on the project again. So far the applied script doesn't work.

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: Well I plugged it in and editted the classes for my needs and it did nothing. I also tried your working example that also did nothing.

Comment: @andrew.bachman: It looks like its not working in Chrome (sorry about that). Is that the browser you're using by any chance?

Comment: @andrew.bachman: I updated the example and answer to work in Chrome/IE/FF. Please let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: Looks like that was the issue but I had tested it out in FF with no avail. The new example works great! Thank you so much I'll implement it into the page and report back.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better idea - use `#hash` links to do the linking, then enhance it with a jQuery. In your HTML:

```
<p>Here's some content <sup><a href="#footnote-1">[1]</a></sup></p>

<ul id="footnotes">
   <li id="footnote-1">Sources: a, b and c</li>
</ul>
```

Notice that the scrolling will work with or without JavaScript enabled, and if the user chooses to save the link by bookmarking it or copying it to somewhere else your page will still work as expected.

Now we define a simple CSS class to highlight the selected footnote:

```
.highlight {
    background: #ddd;
}
```

And we apply some JavaScript logic:

```
// Select all #hash links
$('a[href^=#]').click(function(){
    $('#footnotes li').removeClass('highlight')
        .filter(this.href).addClass('highlight');
});
```

If you want to check whether the user is navigating to a `#hash` URL, you can use `location.hash` to do it:

```
if(location.hash) $(location.hash).addClass('highlight');
```

Answer (score 1):

It is no longer necessary to use jQuery for this; the CSS3 `:target` pseudo-class now does this in a pure-CSS way.

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/fluffycritter/pen/rNNgKNj)

Reference: [How to Dynamically Highlight Content Like Wikipedia Using CSS3](https://www.impressivewebs.com/dynamically-highlight-content-wikipedia-css3/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the better approach would be opening a tooltip with the reference details instead of jumping up and down. Simple and neat plugin is at: http://livereference.org In addition to reading user defined reference it can automatically retrieve publication details from a given ISBN or PubMed ID.